# Count the number of words in a string composed by paragraphs

Tags: javascript, word-count

I'm trying to count the number of words present in a string. This string is composed by 3 paragraphs with 281 words.

I'm using the split.length method, but the word counting I'm getting is 279 and not 281. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in order to be missing 2 words from the counting. Can you help please?

```js
const loremIpsumString = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet ornare ante, iaculis facilisis elit bibendum pulvinar. Vestibulum nec tempor libero, vitae ullamcorper arcu. Pellentesque tempor euismod viverra. Donec et mi at leo ultrices elementum sed sed lectus. Quisque aliquam, urna cursus ornare accumsan, eros turpis sagittis dui, efficitur placerat orci ex sit amet est. Nunc sodales neque elit, quis consequat magna tristique ac. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc volutpat pulvinar neque, non interdum felis varius eget. Praesent dictum eros a purus tempor, et pellentesque ipsum dictum. Nulla ac magna nisl.

Quisque vulputate convallis ex nec venenatis. Nunc hendrerit tristique dictum. Integer posuere sed libero id vestibulum. Aliquam quis elit et massa varius euismod. Maecenas et imperdiet neque. Phasellus aliquet purus sed enim pharetra tempus. Ut euismod facilisis enim, quis dictum nulla pulvinar quis. Donec a est leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin fringilla, quam et feugiat pretium, erat augue pretium eros, ac facilisis eros lectus vel ipsum.

Donec dui libero, sagittis eget auctor sed, dictum in orci. Mauris mollis fermentum purus nec aliquet. In ultricies mi sed tortor vehicula, ut semper ex posuere. Suspendisse commodo massa non sem porta suscipit. In finibus neque vel dolor malesuada mattis. Etiam tincidunt mattis velit nec viverra. Nulla facilisi. Mauris eu odio pharetra, vehicula augue sit amet, accumsan tortor. Sed tempus metus ac gravida scelerisque. Aenean ullamcorper orci id ipsum bibendum, a sollicitudin ligula sagittis. Integer id tellus sit amet enim faucibus consequat. Duis nisi purus, volutpat sit amet fermentum eu, tincidunt non purus. Praesent leo orci, tempor et felis non, suscipit lacinia mi. Nulla a justo sed elit tincidunt imperdiet. Aenean hendrerit vehicula odio, sit amet cursus eros aliquet non. Vestibulum vulputate scelerisque ultricies.`;

const numWords = (loremIpsumString.split(" ").length);

console.log(numWords);
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're splitting the text by the literal space, so the words that are on paragraph boundaries are considered a single "word", e.g. `nisl.\n\nQuisque`. You need to split by any whitespace instead, using a regular expression:

```
const numWords = loremIpsumString.split(/\s+/g).length;
```

This [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) provides an introduction to regular expressions.

When working with dynamic strings, it would be also a good idea to remove leading and trailing whitespace before counting:

```
const numWords = someString.trim().split(/\s+/g).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regexConst = /[a-zA-Z]\w*/g
const loremIpsumString = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet ornare ante, iaculis facilisis elit bibendum pulvinar. Vestibulum nec tempor libero, vitae ullamcorper arcu. Pellentesque tempor euismod viverra. Donec et mi at leo ultrices elementum sed sed lectus. Quisque aliquam, urna cursus ornare accumsan, eros turpis sagittis dui, efficitur placerat orci ex sit amet est. Nunc sodales neque elit, quis consequat magna tristique ac. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc volutpat pulvinar neque, non interdum felis varius eget. Praesent dictum eros a purus tempor, et pellentesque ipsum dictum. Nulla ac magna nisl.

Quisque vulputate convallis ex nec venenatis. Nunc hendrerit tristique dictum. Integer posuere sed libero id vestibulum. Aliquam quis elit et massa varius euismod. Maecenas et imperdiet neque. Phasellus aliquet purus sed enim pharetra tempus. Ut euismod facilisis enim, quis dictum nulla pulvinar quis. Donec a est leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin fringilla, quam et feugiat pretium, erat augue pretium eros, ac facilisis eros lectus vel ipsum.

Donec dui libero, sagittis eget auctor sed, dictum in orci. Mauris mollis fermentum purus nec aliquet. In ultricies mi sed tortor vehicula, ut semper ex posuere. Suspendisse commodo massa non sem porta suscipit. In finibus neque vel dolor malesuada mattis. Etiam tincidunt mattis velit nec viverra. Nulla facilisi. Mauris eu odio pharetra, vehicula augue sit amet, accumsan tortor. Sed tempus metus ac gravida scelerisque. Aenean ullamcorper orci id ipsum bibendum, a sollicitudin ligula sagittis. Integer id tellus sit amet enim faucibus consequat. Duis nisi purus, volutpat sit amet fermentum eu, tincidunt non purus. Praesent leo orci, tempor et felis non, suscipit lacinia mi. Nulla a justo sed elit tincidunt imperdiet. Aenean hendrerit vehicula odio, sit amet cursus eros aliquet non. Vestibulum vulputate scelerisque ultricies.`;

const totalWords = loremIpsumString.match(regexConst).length

console.log(totalWords)
```

will console.log the total amount of words (DOESNT WORK WITH ACCENT MARKS)

Comment: What will this print if you use the OP's name as a test? ;)

Comment: oh yeah i forgot about accent marks, yours will work better because of that